# Unit testing app using node.js and azure functions with SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, azure, unit-testing

How can I start unit testing my application?
First of I wanna test that I can access my SQL database.
Second i wanna test how i can test the creation of a new User

I can't seem to find any documentation on this subject

Which kind of test framework can i use, mocha & chai?

This is my azure function for register

```
    module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try {
        await db.startDb(); //start db connection
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error connecting to the database", error.message)
    }
    
    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            await get(context, req);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            await post(context, req);
            break
        default:
            context.res = {
                body: "Please get or post"
            };
            break
    }
}

async function get(context, req){
    try{
        let name = req.query.name;
        let user = await db.select(name)
        context.res = {
            body: user
        };
    } catch(error){
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: `No user - ${error.message}`
        }
    }
}

async function post(context, req){
    try{
        let payload = req.body;
        await db.insert(payload)
        console.log(payload)
        
        context.res = {
            body: ["succes"]
        }
    } catch(error){
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: error.message
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my DB file**

```
const { Connection, Request, TYPES } = require('tedious');
const config = require('./config.json');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const safeJWT = require("../middleware/Jwt")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

var connection = new Connection(config);

function startDb() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.on('connect', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Connection failed')
                reject(err)
                throw (err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connected')
                resolve();
            }
        })
        connection.connect();
    })
}
module.exports.sqlConnection = connection
module.exports.startDb = startDb
```

**This is some of my register.js file**

```
    fetch("http://localhost:7071/api/register", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset-UTF-8"
        }
    }).then((response) =>
        response.json()).then((data) => {
            if(data[0] = "succes"){
            location.href = "login.html"
            } else {
                alert("failed")
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well Unit tests are done in isolation and they are testing one unit. You should not test database and etc., if you want to test user creation with the database that will be e2e test.

For unit tests mock the database calls.